# Enthought canopy not running

Tags: windows, installation, enthought, canopy

I installed Enthought Canopy onto my 64 bit windows box (Windows 7).

Installed "successfully" except Canopy would not run at all from start menu.  I tried running it from cmd and it still would not run.

I checked c:\Users\user...Local and Roaming and found no error logs.

I tried the Windows Vista and above with User Access Control (UAC) enabled, the msi installer trick but Canopy still didn't run either from start menu or cmd.

There seems no help on this on the Enthought website, has anyone else seen and solved the problem?

Comment: It is hard to guess what the problem is. Could you expand your post to add specific error messages or anything you see when you run canopy from the command prompt. You should consider submitting a bug through the platform, because the log files will be collected automatically.

Comment: Are you sure there are no log files here:? C:\Users\<your-user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\log\ . You can zip them up and email them, with your description, to canopy.support@enthought.com (though we do appreciate that, as a free user, you used Stack Overflow for this initial inquiry.)

Comment: I was having this same problem. Following the advice below, I deleted the PYTHONPATH environment variable and Canopy started working. @JonathanMarch, in my opinion, this is something the installer should warn me about, and subsequently correct with my consent. As it stands, the installer left me in a bogus state.

Comment: @Mike, in the future, Canopy will guard agains inappropriate use of Pythonpath (i.e. pointing into a site-packages). Appropriate use (pointing at your own python files) will not cause any problems. More information here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-

Comment: To original poster: in addition, PYTHONHOME can also cause troubles. See this article https://support.enthought.com/entries/22508619-Windows-Canopy-shortcut-in-Start-menu-doesn-t-do-anything

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late as you may already have saolved your problem. But I get the same problem after installing.

Did you install a standalone version of python and have a PYTHONPATH variable already defined?

By me, I just remove the PYTHONPATH variable and then Canopy starts correctly